# Created a database design for sale of moterbikes wan to know the if the relations are correct or not

Tags: database-design, erd, java

[image: i have given one to one relation b/w payment and orderdetails in my entity with jpa but in erd it is 1 to many]

i have given one to one relation b/w payment and orderdetails in my entity with jpa but in erd it is 1 to many

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.